# ORDER BY depending on the column type

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

My table is as below:

```
a | b
-----
1 | a
2 | b
```

In my query, I want to change the order by clause depending on the type of the column.

So something like

```
get_data($order_by_column) {

  ....
  ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN is_numeric($order_by_column) THEN $order_by_column
      ELSE CHAR_LENGTH($order_by_column)
    END
}
```

I've checked and it seems it's quite difficult to determine the column type dynamically like in the above query. What would be an alternative (or alternatives) to achieve this?

Comment: Pass the type additionally to column name

Comment: @zerkms: There is really no need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be interested in [**`pg_typeof()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE):

```
ORDER BY
   CASE pg_typeof($order_by_column)
      WHEN 'integer'::regtype THEN $order_by_column
--    WHEN 'text'::regtype THEN ...
--    WHEN 'boolean'::regtype THEN ...
      ELSE length($order_by_column)
   END
```

Note that the legs of a `CASE` statement need to return matching types, which happens to be the case here, since `$order_by_column` and `length($order_by_column)` both return `integer`.

More about [object identifier types like `regtype` in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html).

Find all registered types:

```
SELECT * from pg_type
```

Again, more about [`pg_type` in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html).